# craft.entries and lightswitch

Tags: entries

This is super simple, and I don't get why it's not working.

```
{% set results = craft.entries.section('events').lightSwitchField('1') %}
```

Returns all entries in Events where the light switch field is green.

```
{% set results = craft.entries.section('events').lightSwitchField('0') %}
```

Returns all entries in Events. Period. Not all entries that the lightswitch is set to off.

I want to get all entries where the lightswitch field is off. Later I'm going to chain some other fields to the query too.

What have I not understood about how this works?

Comment: Have you tried using `true` and `false` in place of `'1'` and `'0`'?

Comment: I had, it makes no difference. Answer was provided by Lindsey below: it's a Craft quirk :/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is a known behavioral issue. PHP considers `0`, `"0"`, `false`, and similar values to be [“empty”](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues), and Craft only factors most criteria param values into the query if they are not empty. So setting a Lightswitch field’s criteria param to `'0'` is the same as not setting it at all.

The workaround is to use `not 1`:

```
{% set results = craft.entries.section('events').lightSwitchField('not 1') %}
```

Comment: I've just faced this problem, and it looks like in Craft 3 it's looking for true (or false / not true)